# Python While Not recordset.EOF that wont .MoveNext

Tags: python, while-loop, python-2.7, recordset, win32com

I don't really understand why this is happening.  Maybe a fresh set of eyes could help.

in the table of an access database, say C:\dbase.mdb, I have a table called tProcedureGroups with two fields, ID and Description.

```
ID  Description  
1   DIAGNOSTIC  
2   PREVENTATIVE  
3   RESTORATIVE
```

So my recordset should be a lot more than an infinite... ID "\t" + Description + "\n"
Here's my code...  this had to of happened to a few of you python gurus out there!

Thanks so much for your help, everyone on this site seems super helpful.

---

```
import win32com.client

def Procedures(listed):
    DB = r"C:\dbase.mdb"
    engine = win32com.client.Dispatch("DAO.DBEngine.36")
    db = engine.OpenDatabase(DB)
    sql = "select * from [tProcedureGroups]"
    access = db.OpenRecordset(sql)
    while not access.EOF:
        for i in listed:
            print i + '\t' + str(access.Fields(i).value) + '\n'
        access.MoveNext

fields = ["ID", "Description"]
get_procs = Procedures(fields)
```

Comment: I suggest you drop the while-loops tag and add the python tag to get maximum visibility to the python gurus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you need to call methods explicitly with ().

So change:

```
access.MoveNext
```

to

```
access.MoveNext()
```

Comment: ARG!  thank you so much for that.  after you mentioned that I looked at the other parts I DID have working and just noticed that I had used () for them, but missed them this time.